# Уменьшить дублирование кода RxJava

Tags: android, rxjava, repository

Использую `MVP` + `Room` + `RxJava` + `Repository`.

И вот в нескольких презентах идет явное дублирование кода.

К примеру

```
   private void gettingAWallet(@NonNull final String getWalletAddress) {
    repository.gettingAWallet(userState.getEmail(), getWalletAddress).subscribe(new DisposableMaybeObserver<PurseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(PurseUser purse) {
            purseUser = purse;
            exchangeView.inizilizationUI(purseUser.getTypePurseEnum().getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            // ...
            Log.e("getAccount", "OmError");
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            MessageUtils.showCustomMessage(context, context.getString(R.string.transitionError), context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
        }
    });
}
```

и в другом презенте

```
    private void gettingAWallet(@NonNull final String getWalletAddress) {
    repository.gettingAWallet(userState.getEmail(), getWalletAddress).subscribe(new DisposableMaybeObserver<PurseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(PurseUser purse) {
            purseUser = purse;
            addFundsView.updateUI(purseUser);

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            // ...
            Log.e("getAccount", "OmError");
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            MessageUtils.showCustomMessage(context, context.getString(R.string.transitionError), context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
        }
    });
}
```

Всё одинаковое, кроме реализации в методе`onSuccess()`. Как можно вынести всё остальное для повторного использования

Comment: Используйте абстрактный класс

Comment: Спасибо, вроде как сделал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил с помощью абстрактного класса. Может кому пригодится, или предложит по лучше реализацию. Так как я вызываю диалоговые окна, то в конструктор передаю Context и String

```
public abstract class DisposableMaybeAbstract<T> extends DisposableMaybeObserver<T> {

    @NonNull
    private Context context;

    @NonNull
    private String onComplete;

    @NonNull
    private String onError;

    public DisposableMaybeAbstract(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String onComplete, @NonNull String onError) {
        this.context = context;
        this.onComplete = onComplete;
        this.onError = onError;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        MessageUtils.showCustomMessage(context, onError, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        MessageUtils.showCustomMessage(context, onComplete, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
    }
}
```

И теперь мои методы имеют такую структуру

```
 private void gettingAWallet(@NonNull final String getWalletAddress) {
    repository.gettingAWallet(userState.getEmail(), getWalletAddress).subscribe(new DisposableMaybeAbstract<PurseUser>(context, context.getString(R.string.purseNull), context.getString(R.string.transitionError)) {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(PurseUser purse) {
            purseUser = purse;
            exchangeView.inizilizationUI(purseUser.getTypePurseEnum().getId());
        }
    });
}
```